# How much a decimal degree is equal to in latitude 40N?

Tags: latitude-longitude

I would like to learn how much a decimal degree equals to 40N latitude as units of distance. I have this table (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees) in mind, but I am interested for the latitude 40N.

Comment: [Calculator by NGA](http://msi.nga.mil/MSISiteContent/StaticFiles/Calculators/degree.html) and you can right-click the page and view the calculations via the document 'source.'

Comment: At which bearing?  Even along a single line of latitude, as the direction of travel changes, the decimal degrees required to travel some linear distance changes.  The problem resolves to a partial differential equation, which is generally solved by numerical methods.

Answer (score 3):

When you click on [Latitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude) at your Wikipedia page you find this formula:

[image]

with

```
a (equatorial radius): 6,378,137.0 m exactly
e² (eccentricity squared): 0.006,694,379,990,14
```

For an approximation the term `(1-e² sin² Φ)` is close to 0, so you get

`πa cosΦ / 180 = 111.319km cosΦ`

You can do another approach:

```
length of equator: U = 2πa = 2 * π * 6378137 m = 40075016 m
lenght of one degree: 40075 km/ 360 = 111.319 km
```

All longitude have an equal lenght of 111319 m, for latitude you use simple trigonomety (considering the earth as a sphere) -> `111.319km cosΦ`

So, for 40° N it gives

```
111.319km cos 40° = 82.275 km
```

Comment: For a trivial question I don't have any problem to provide (or accept) a simple answer. The fist sentence of the Wikipedia already refer to [latitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude) and [longitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude) where you get more details. Apparently marika did not read even the first line of the article he posted himself.

Comment: I think the automatic criticism should also consider the length of the question!

Comment: Unfortunately the Wikipedia entry doesn't give the equations used to build the table, nor a link to another article that does (that I noticed). Hmmm, do I have the time to try to update it...?